# Auto Merge in perfoce

Tags: perforce, osb, perforce-client-spec

Hi I have below branches in perforce, (4B, 4B2, 4C1), Now I want that my code can auto-merge from 4B -> 4B2 -> 4C1. This is OSB code. It has pipelines, business services, Xqueries, etc

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:  Live a good life free of karmic burden, and make a wish upon a star that you will not have any merge conflicts.

Step 2:

```
p4 switch 1105-OSBSIT-4B2
p4 merge --from 1104-OSB-SIT-4B
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit

p4 switch 1106-OSB-SIT-4C1
p4 merge --from 1105-OSBSIT-4B2
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit
```

If step 2 doesn't work you messed up some part of step 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'm new to perforce, where do we write these commands?

Comment: A command prompt.  (If you don't know how to open a command prompt, you can open one from P4V by clicking File > Open Command Window.)   You can perform the same operations from P4V but it's a lot more complicated (requires navigating a bunch of dialogs).

Comment: Hi Sam, what if I want to merge a particular file/folder not the whole stream: `p4 switch 1106-OSB-SIT-4C1/Service/Document/...` It is giving me the error: "Stream '//VFI/1106-OSB-SIT-4C1/Service/Document/...' is not the correct format of '//depotname/string"

Comment: Add the filename to the `p4 merge` command, not the `p4 switch` command.

Comment: e.g. `p4 merge --from STREAMNAME FILENAME`.  Use the filename in the *current* stream, not the source stream (or add the `-s` flag if you do need to specify the file as an absolute path in terms of the source's namespace).